# Why Doesn't My HTML Message Display Correctly in Outlook?

Tags: html, razor, outlook

```
tr:nth-child(odd) {
background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
```

My code is working on alla web browsers but not in outlook. I need to Add Alternate Row Color. How can i achieve this ?

Comment: email clients specially outlook restricts some css styles so you have to write specific css for the email clients and try avoiding the use of nth-child as it will be totally ignored by most of the email clients

Comment: i suggest to use the inline styles to get the desired results

Comment: its a dynamic email design, how can i do this using inline styles but keep the dynamic foreach for the grid.

Answer (score 1):

Outlook's parser is nowhere near HTML5 nor CSS3 compliant.

You can learn what it *does* support [in this webpage](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/email-client/outlook-2007-16/).

My suggestion, and what I had to do for my company, is to use a pre-processor to tag what are known to be "odd" with a class like `<tr class="odd">...</tr>`

And have a stylesheet with the rule:

```
tr.odd {
background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
```

Inline styles are also par for Outlook emails, but it is a brute force solution that is very frowned upon in HTML5, so it is a bad habit to get into.